Data Validation, formula to allow 6 digits but no symbols
I am trying to enter a custom data validation with a formula that will only allow 6 digits in the cell but no symbols. For instance we want it has to be AZ1234 (example) but can not be AZ-123. Both of these are 6 digits which is mandatory but we do NOT want a -
I have not found anything that makes sense to me on this

digits means numbers, but you include text.  Is it 6 total characters with a mismatch of text and numbers that are allowed?

And what about case, does it matter?

Yes - The field I am using will have 2 letters and 4 numbers. We used to have 2 letters a dash and 3 numbers. We are changing it so we want to lock it down to include 6 digits (2 letters and 4 numbers, this does not have to be specified ) but want to make sure no dashes are included

Nope, it does not have to, but if there is something that will work and require the letters to be capitalized, I will take it

Interesting, I think you would have to define all characters to be excluded implicitly, such as :
=AND(LEN(A1)=6, OR(ISERROR(FIND("-",A1),ISERROR(FIND("+",A1)...)))
which would make for a rather cumbersome formula but I'm very curious to see what others with come up with.

Ya, I am not a pro at formulas but have no idea what to do for this one. At the very least I was hoping to just find a formula that required 6 digits (does not matter if it is letters or numbers) and then reject if it has a dash (-)

Is this for a single cell or for a column in a table? Can you use a helper column (or cell) for the test?

The following will make sure the first two are letters and capitalized, and that the last 4 are numbers.  As well as only allow 6 characters:
=AND(CODE(LEFT(A1))>64,CODE(LEFT(A1))<91,CODE(MID(A1,2,1))>64,CODE(MID(A1,2,1))<91,ISNUMBER(--RIGHT(A1,4)),LEN(A1)=6,ISERR(FIND("-",A1)),ISERR(FIND("+",A1)))



Also if you have it available:
=REGEXTEST(K2,"^[a-zA-Z]{2}\d{4}$")


Or for upper case only:
=REGEXTEST(K2,"^[A-Z]{2}\d{4}$")


It doesn't cover all the bases but would help to exclude entries such as AB-1234 instead of AB1234:
=AND(LEN(A1)=6, ISNUMBER(MID(A1,3,4)*1), ISERROR(FIND("-",A1)), EXACT(LEFT(A1,2), UPPER(LEFT(A1,2))))


This formula allows values like 123456. EXACT/UPPER don't check that the first two values are letters.

This works for me if I put it in one cell. Is there a way to easily add this to a column of cells? For instance D11-D65 cells

@JessicaCupp - just highlight the range you want to apply it to and enter the formula with the address of the first cell.


Go to Data tab and click Data Validation
Click "Data validation" in dropdown list
On the opened window select "Custom" in "Allow:"
Paste the following code into "Formula"


=AND(LEN(A1)=6,ISNUMBER(SUMPRODUCT(SEARCH(MID(A1,ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&LEN(A1))),1),"ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789"))))

it must work for you.

Hi, I have pasted this formula in the data validation custom section but it does not allow the text that I am needing. I tried AZ1234 I tried UT5555 and neither of those were allowed to be entered but are good examples of what should be allowed.

To validate whether it works or not, first remove all data validations that is assigned to your desired cell (I'm assuming it is A1 from now on). Then add the function to your B1 cell as normal function from function bar. When you change the value of A1, the B1 should return "TRUE" if the context is wrong it should return "FALSE".
It might not work due to several reasons:
-- You might assign another data validation before
-- You might try to assign data validation to a cell that is not "A1" (in this case replace A1 with your appropriate cell address)

If available, REGEXTEST would be the first choice, otherwise here's another option using SEQUENCE:

Change A1 to the active cell in your range for validation
Changing the formula in the validation dialog could be difficult, so,

Copy this and enter in an empty cell
Update all instances of A1 to the correct first cell in your range and press enter
Result will reflect the validity of the first cell
Copy this updated formula to your clipboard and use it in validation



=AND(
  LEN(A1) = 6,
  UPPER(MID(A1, SEQUENCE(, 2), 1)) >= "A",
  UPPER(MID(A1, SEQUENCE(, 2), 1)) <= "Z",
  MID(A1, SEQUENCE(, 4, 3), 1) >= "0",
  MID(A1, SEQUENCE(, 4, 3), 1) <= "9"
)

